# read number occurrence from file with no delimiter c++

Tags: c++, file, c++11, integer, delimiter

I have a working prototype with the code being read from the file. My problem is figuring out how to read it from the file without any spaces. For my code below to work properly, the file's contents needs to look like this:
3 4 6 2 5

What I'm looking to put in the file is this:
34625

and for my output I am hoping for this:

3 occurs 4 times
4 occurs 5 times
5 occurs 6 times
6 occurs 7 times

I am also wondering if there is a way to print the numbers without initializing the array. In my code I have 12 as the numbers in the file. But is there a way to have "unknown" just in case later the user wants to add more integers to read from the file?

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//NEEDS to read numbers WITHOUT SPACES!!
int main()
{
  ifstream theFile ("inputData.txt");
  int MaxRange= 9;
  char c;
  int myint[12]={0};
  int mycompare[12]={0};
  int mycount[12] = {0};
  int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
  for(j=0;j <= MaxRange;j++){
    mycompare[j] = j;
  }

  do
  {
    theFile>>myint[i];
    for(j=0;j<=MaxRange;j++)
    {
      if(myint[i] == mycompare[j])
        mycount[j] = mycount[j]+1;
    }
    i++;
  }
  while((myint[i] >=0) && (myint[i] <= MaxRange));

  for(j=0; j <=MaxRange; j++)
  {
    if(isdigit(j)) 
      ++j;
    cout<< j<< " occurs: "<<mycount[j]<<endl;  
  }
}
```

Comment: From your question, it is not clear which array you are attempting to not initialize.  That said, Most of your arrays are not needed at all.  If all you want to do is count the number of 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 in the file, it can be done with a little math instead. As to reading the values without being space delimited, it might be easier to read them in 1 character at a time instead of as an int, then convert the char to an integer.  I know how to do this in C, but there is probably a C++ way to do this instead with streams.

Comment: And as for file size, you really are only reading in things 1 number at a time.  Therefore, the only thing you need is a single integer buffer, than an array to keep track of your digit count.  `mycompare`, and array for `myint` are both a waste.  Having more than 10 entries into your `mycount` is also a waste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example to start with (change `cin` with file)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<int, int> m;
    char c;
    while (cin >> c)
        m[c - '0']++;
    for (auto i : m)
        cout << i.first << " occurs " << i.second << " times" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Input

```
34625
```

Output

```
2 occurs 1 times
3 occurs 1 times
4 occurs 1 times
5 occurs 1 times
6 occurs 1 times
```

Comment: This is definitely very helpful. I am so close and it working, the problem I am having is it's outputting - numbers as well. I will spend some times fixing up the code. I will upvote this comment if I may no more questions.

Comment: perfect, works nice. Thanks, everyone for your help. For this one it was giving out negative results so I added if(isdigit(c)) between the while to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use char type to read from the file? With char you can read character by character and count them. It maybe better to use switch-case structure instead of "for" to count.
Last paragraph is not clear for me.

Comment: Giving you a +1 back because "gimme the codez" markdown is incredibly rude and not fair.

Comment: As I understand, you have  a file that contain only digits and you want to write a code to count each digit (0 to 9).
Correct if I am wrong. I need to know what you want to do (exactly), and I will write code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer- below code is not compiled or tested.  You turn this in as-is and you get what you get.

Notice how I have changed the file read (`cin`) to use a char instead of an integer.  This allows me to read the file 1 char at a time.  Also notice that I've changed to range to 10, because there are 10 possible digits (remember 0), and have set my count array to this size.  Also notice that this will work with any file size, though it may fail if there are are more than 2 Billion integers of 1 value in the file (integer overflow) on a 32-bit system.

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream theFile ("inputData.txt");
  const int MaxRange= 10;
  char c;
  int mycount[MaxRange] = {0};

  // Check for eof each loop.  This may not be the best way to do this, 
  // but it demonstrates the concept.

  // A much better way is to put the cin assign right in the while loop parenthesis- 
  // this replaces and catches the eof automatically.
  while(!cin.eof())
  {
    theFile>>c;

    // If the char isn't a digit, we ignore it.
    if(!isdigit(c))
      continue;

    // Convert char to integer.
    int value = c + '0';

    // Update count array.
    mycount[value]++;
  }

  // Print the final array for each value.  You could skip counts
  // of zero if you would like with a little extra logic.
  for(int j=0; j<MaxRange; j++)
  {
    cout<< j<< " occurs: "<<mycount[j]<<endl;  
  }
}
```

Comment: Also beware that this will fail horribly if it can't find the input file, if the file is not ASCII, etc.

Comment: Hello Michael, thanks for the code. I fixed a few things, however now it's not reading at all. The output is 0 occurs 0 times, 1 occurs 0 times, etc.

Comment: Again, untested code is untested.  At this point, it would be excellent to actually step through the above code in a debugger and see why it is failing.  If I had a guess, it is how I am handling the eof() or on the isdigit check.  Putting a break point and stepping through will show for sure where the issue exists.

Comment: You could also try putting the `theFile>>c` line directly in the while loop check, replacing the eof, as I suggest.